# Multitouch in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, multi-touch

I have two questions:

1. How to simulate touch event in linux.
2. How to work with multitouch on Qt in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate touch events by calling `qt_translateRawTouchEvent` directly. (This method is not documented, but it's in `qapplication.cpp` and it's exported).

You want to put this at the top of your file:

```
// forward-declaration of Qt internal function
Q_GUI_EXPORT void qt_translateRawTouchEvent(QWidget *window, 
                                        QTouchEvent::DeviceType deviceType,
                                        const QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> &touchPoints);
```

The function call syntax is :

```
qt_translateRawTouchEvent(targetWidget, deviceType, points.values());
```

In your case call this method with `(NULL, QTouchEvent::TouchScreen, touchPoints)` where `touchPoints` is your list of points being currently touched by the user.
This should work in Qt 4.7 and 4.8 at least, possibly before in Qt 5 but I didn't check that.

Answer (score 3):

For the multitouch question, you are probably wanting to have a look at the [Gestures API](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/gestures-overview.html) that Qt has added.

Comment: Ок, but how I can simulate touch in Linux?
I need to simulate gesture.

Comment: @Alex Snet: I don't know how to simulate the touch event.  When you ask multiple questions like this, you need to expect some people may only know the answer to one of them.